# Scientific name of rolling median applied for times series outliers detection algorithm

Tags: time-series, outliers

I am a beginner in Machine Learning. I have a small python module related to times series outliers detection. I found in some posts and blogs an algorithm using thresholds calculated based on the rolling (or moving) median and moving standard deviation like in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46964363/filtering-out-outliers-in-pandas-dataframe-with-rolling-median) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62692771/outlier-detection-based-on-the-moving-mean-in-python).

```
df['median']= df['b'].rolling(window).median()
df['std'] = df['b'].rolling(window).std()
#filter setup
df = df[(df.b <= df['median']+3*df['std']) & (df.b >= df['median']-3*df['std'])]
```

- Question 1 : Is there a scientific name for this algorithm?
- Question 2 : Is there a reference for this algorithm?

Thank you very much in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

It is called Repeated Running Medians, usually you start off with a large window size and at each time decrease it.
The algorithm is credited to Tukey and most references are to his book:  "Exploratory data analysis" Addison-Wesley; 1977.

The application of it to TS to detect outliers is used extensively, see for example the SEE algorithm, which uses RRM with LOWESS in order to smooth and segment movement - [SEE](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0149763401000227).

Comment: Are you sure about this? OP asked about outlier detection, running medians is a smoothing technique.

Comment: Repeated Running Median (RRM), is the reference to running median. The 3 SD rule to detect outlier (of change in distribution) is credited to Shewart AFAIK. I am not aware to a specific algorithm employing RM and this rule.